# How install composer-asset-plugin while 'vagrant up'?

Tags: shell, vagrant, composer-php, expect, puphpet

I generate config by [puphpet.com](http://puphpet.com). I want to install `composer-asset-plugin` when I first run `vagrant up`.

I wrote simple script `puphpet\files\exec-once\composer-asset-plugin.sh`, which tries to do that:

`#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Installing Composer Asset Plugin"
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.0"`

It install plugin in `/root/.composer`, so when I connect via `vagrant ssh` (under user `vagrant`) and try to use Composer I get a error, which means that plugin is absent because Composer really absent in `/home/vagrant/.composer`. After I install plugin malualy Composer works fine.

I tried to change user from `root` to `vagrant` before plugin instaling:

`#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Installing Composer Asset Plugin"
expect -c 'set timeout 3600; spawn su - vagrant; expect "Password:" {send -- "vagrant\r";}; exit 0'
composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.0;`

It hangs after command `expect`. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following might help:

```
# Install Composer
if [ ! -f /usr/local/bin/composer ]; then
    cd /tmp
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
fi
# Install necessary plugin
sudo -H -u vagrant bash -c "composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.0"
```

In this case the command will be executed in vagrant user context and his home will be used.

Comment: It returns `sudo: composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.0": command not found`

Comment: Looks like you don't have composer installed yet, check updated answer please.